# How to handle Timer events for multiple calls in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer

I have methods as below

```
public static class PublisherClass {
    public static async Task PublishToMethod(string methodName, string message) {
        switch (methodName) {
        case "start":
            PayloadCreator.SetTimer(timeInterval);
        }
    }
}

public static class PayloadCreator {

    public static void SetTimer(int timeInterval) {     
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeInterval);
        aTimer.Elapsed += SendPeriodic;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static async void SendPeriodic(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {      
        Console.WriteLine("Starting to send periodic Telemetry at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", e.SignalTime);
        await SendPeriodicTimeSeries(PublisherClass.TimeSeriesTopic, PublisherClass.TelemetrySingle, PublisherClass.Configuration);
        await SendPeriodicAlarm(PublisherClass.AlarmTopic, PublisherClass.AlarmSingle);     
    }
}
```

Whenever the call comes to 'PublishToMethod', Timer is started and keeps sending periodic invocation of certain things. I felt the Timer code is not asynchronous fully. If I invoked two times it behaves differently. The periodic Time Interval got broken.

My sequence of scenario is as below
1. Call PublishToMethod(string methodName, string message) with 'message' parameter as below json. 'methodName' is 'start'

```
{
  "input": {
    "payload": {
      "objectId": "123"
    },
    "configuration": {
      "timeInterval": 10000,
      "variables": [
        "numberVar.number",
        "stringVar.string",
        "boolVar.boolean"          
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Then I send the telemetry data on 10s interval as in the payload as *'timeInterval'*.
3. Then I again invoke the 'PublishToMethod' with different data and time interval as below

   {
     "input": {
       "payload": {
         "objectId": "456"
       },
       "configuration": {
         "timeInterval": 5000,
         "variables": [
           "integerVar.integer"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
4. So Timer works seamlessly by serving these different data and keep sending the telemetry data

Currently it just works fine for one set of data.

My need is to run the Timer invoked methods for multiple calls to the Timer. Each call will run independently with different set of data. How can I achieve?

Looks like through static class I might not able to achieve since I can't able to handle multiple instances.

Comment: Please explain better the behavior you're seeing and what is wrong with it. System.Timers.Timer will invoke the elapsed event handler using the thread pool, which means that if the previous call is not yet done, a new call will start to run in parallel. Additionally, your event handler is async and uses await. What do you mean that this is not "asynchronous fully"? What did you expect it to do that it doesn't?

Comment: if this is a case of precision (for example, you want to run `SendPeriodic` every 50ms) - `System.Timers.Timer` is not a right choice

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen As soon as the 'start' is invoked for the first time 'SendPeriodic' method got invoked and as per the 'timeInterval' it got triggered periodically. But when the second time 'start' is invoked it's not following the 'timeInterval'. I can't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have here is not one of asynchrony, it is the fact that your `PayloadCreator` is a static class, and given the method signatures, your timer is also static.

Static items are instantiated once in the lifetime of your app domain - in this case, every time you call `SetTimer`, you are changing the properties of the timer used by all the other previous calls to `PublishToMethod`.

I can't tell you how to restructure this, as I am unsure what your requirements are, but if the timer needs to be different across different 'published' items, then you cannot keep this static structure.

Comment: Yes you are right. My idea is to send multiple calls in various times to 'PublishToMethod' that invokes 'start' method separately with different data. Each I want them to run parallelly.